# How to set read-only attribute on file

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-addin, file, spfile

I have .docx file on sharepoint which should be read only but I do not know how to set this attribute in my sharepoint application in c# code behind. How to set read-only attribute on file in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Try This, Declare a Client context ctx and get your list/library name:

```
RoleDefinition roleDef =  ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection( ctx );
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            roleDefBinding.Add( roleDef );
CamlQuery query;
            query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems( query );
            ctx.Load( items );
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var grp = cpx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);  
            foreach ( Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items )
            {
                ctx.Load( item, i=>i.RoleAssignments, i=>i.HasUniqueRoleAssignments );
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                if ( !item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments )
                {
                    item.BreakRoleInheritance( true, false );
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                item.RoleAssignments.Add( grp, roleDefBinding );
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Comment: It seems to look good but in my application unfortunately it does not work. I have an Error: Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection.

Comment: Have you declared a client context "ctx" as i said. See below How I declare it

Comment: ClientContext ctx= new ClientContext("https://yoursite/sites/AnkitTest/");
                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                var usernameqw = "ankitk@D.onmicrosoft.com";
                var pwdqq = "yourpwd";
                foreach (char c in pwdqq)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }
                var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(usernameqw, securePassword);
                ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCollection grpcol = web.SiteGroups;
                ctx.Load(grpcol);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: I belive that my contex is declared correctly. An error occured on line with: item.RoleAssignments.Add( grp, roleDefBinding );

Comment: put debugger and check if its really empty. It shouldn't come as far i see the code.